# Why large linear systems of saddle point type are indefiniteness and often poor spectral properties?

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I'm reading the paper "Numerical solution of saddle point problems" by Michele Benzi. In the abstract, he states that these types of large linear systems of saddle point are challenging due to their indefiniteness and often poor spectral properties.

And I cannot understand what does he means with indefiniteness (what makes this type of linear system have this characteristic? what this implies to the system?)and with poor spectral properties (what makes this type of linear system have this characteristic? what this implies to the system?)

I'm new with the subject of matter, if is self-evident please be kind.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Indefinite means the matrix has both positive and negative eigenvalues. Poor spectral properties means that the eigenvalues are spread out widely (not clustered in groups). This causes krylov methods to converge slowly when using them to solve linear systems with the matrix.